# Removing Word table border using C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I wanted to perform specific table formatting by removing left, right, inside horizontal and inside vertical borders. I have recorded a macro for this and got the following VBA code. I tried to make the same using C# , but I could not find there properties like `wdBorderLeft` ,  `wdBorderRight`, `wdBorderHorizontal` or `wdBorderVertical`. Does anyone know how to perform the same method using C#. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Sarah

```
Sub Macro6()
   Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
   Selection.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
   Selection.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
   Selection.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
End Sub`
```

Comment: Do what Andy said. Specify your context! =/ I was going to say I want a pony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer may be on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955%28VS.80%29.aspx.

Add:
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Then use:
    newTable.Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft)

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that you could do with the Interop.Word is simple disable the borders from your table, ie:

Table.Borders.Enable = 0;

That gets rid of everything in one simple line.